# Is Documentation available through Mobile app

Tags: support, documentation, mobile-web, ios-app

I'm a user of the Stack Exchange app. I search through settings but seems like maybe I couldn't find documentation tab. I know it exists because I read a Google News article about it.

However, my browser is Dolphin for IPhones. I cannot figure out how to get to documentation.

Any warriors understand the secrets behind documentation?

Answer (score 6):

You can acces documentation by manually navigating to https://stackoverflow.com/documentation or loading any link references to documentation in answers.  Documentation is, however, not optimized for mobile nor available in the native app [yet].